# "Neglected" or "long-forgotten"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, translation

Good day. I'm translating to English the term "lazos olvidados" (from Spanish). It applies to a group of youths that are children of immigrants in a certain country, which go back to their parent's country of origin, in order to restore a bond with a country that they come from in blood and/or from early childhood, but they don't know anymore due to having lived their whole lives in their adoptive country.

My question is which term is better for this concept, the bonds have been "neglected" or "long-forgotten"? I'm not very sure about using 'neglected' because I see a little negativity in that term.

Can anyone help me to clear this issue?

Comment: I think I would use ties, rather than bonds. There are plenty of references using: ties to their home countries and variations of that.  I would translate it as: Forgotten Ties.

Comment: Thank you,  Lambie. 'Ties' is a very nice alternative to bonds, and relevant to this context.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for *long-forgotten*.

The word *neglected* implies that the people in their home country deliberately ignored them (which is presumably why you rightly think it's a negative term).

[**neglect**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/neglect):

> - to pay no attention or too little attention to; disregard or slight:
>     *The public neglected his genius for many years.*
> - to be remiss in the care or treatment of:
>     *to neglect one's family*; *to neglect one's appearance.*
> - to omit, through indifference or carelessness:
>     *to neglect to reply to an invitation*.

[**forget**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/forget):

> - to cease or fail to remember; be unable to recall:
>     *to forget someone's name*.
> - to omit or neglect unintentionally:
>     *I forgot to shut the window before leaving*.
> - to leave behind unintentionally; neglect to take:
>     *to forget one's keys*.

You can see that *forget* has the element of unintentionality, whereas *neglect* is more deliberate (though this is not too obvious from the definition).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation!! It is really useful. :) And yes, that's how I see 'neglect', like it was intentional or something.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that "neglected" has somewhat negative connotations. However, I also suggest to consider that the ties mentioned may be ***neither*** "neglected" nor "long-forgotten."

It feels to me that for immigrants' children who grew up in an adopted country, the ties to their native country may never have been forged in the first place. So a word to express that idea might be more useful... like, for example, ***nonexistent***

Of course, this probably changes the sense so much that it's no longer an accurate translation of the original Spanish phrase.

Comment: But the implication is that they *are* existent. Because they have ties to these origins, namely their parents, or their parents' family (grandparents, uncles, siblings, etc.), which they go to look for at said country of origin.

Comment: Not to split hairs, but it could be argued that the ties are of their relatives, not theirs directly. If, for example, the children were separated from their parents after immigrating, then their experience would be quite different. Obviously, I wouldn't know the context, because I've not read the original. But it's not outside the realm of possibility.  In any case, it's just a thought meant to cover all bases.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I didn't get a notification in my email about your comment. I'm not sure what you mean, to be honest. Even if they were separated when they were children from that country, and from those relatives, the ties are still there, even if it's only by their blood. "Nonexistent" means that there are absolutely no ties whatsoever, of ANY kind.

Answer (score 0):

Google Translate give "forgotten ties". "Neglected" gives more of a sense that there is something they could have been doing to maintain the ties. Other terms to consider would be

"fade":

> gradually grow faint and disappear.
>   "the noise faded away"
>   synonyms:   dim, grow dim, grow faint, fail, dwindle, die away, wane, disappear, vanish, decline, melt away; literaryevanesce
>   "the afternoon light began to fade"
>   antonyms:   increase
>   lose or cause to lose color or brightness.
>   "the fair hair had faded to a dusty gray"
>   synonyms:   become pale, become bleached, become washed out, lose color, discolor; More
>   antonyms:   brighten, enhance
>   (of a flower) lose freshness and wither.
>   synonyms:   wither, wilt, droop, shrivel, die
>   "remove the flower heads as they fade"
>   gradually become thin and weak, especially to the point of death.
>   (of a racehorse, runner, etc.) lose strength or drop back, especially after a promising start.
>   "she faded near the finish"
>   (of a radio signal) gradually lose intensity.
>   "the signal faded away"
>   (of a vehicle brake) become temporarily less efficient as a result of frictional heating.

or

"atrophy":

> gradually decline in effectiveness or vigor due to underuse or neglect.

BTW, you might consider asking on a Spanish-specific SE.

Comment: "BTW, you might consider asking on a Spanish-specific SE." You mean with Spanish-speakers? The thing is, my question is about English meaning, not Spanish. But thank you for these ideas.